# Pandas DataFrame groupby, count and sum across columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like the following. It has the cumulative vehicle counts over time.

[Image Describing the Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Nef.png)

```
LcounterCar,LcounterTruck,LcounterBus,LcounterMotorcycle,LcounterVan,Ltime,RcounterCar,RcounterTruck,RcounterBus,RcounterMotorcycle,RcounterVan,Rtime

1,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:22:00,,,,,
2,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:23:00,,,,,
3,1,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:23:00,,,,,
4,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:24:00,,,,,
5,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:25:00,,,,,
6,2,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:25:00,,,,,
,,,,,,1,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:25:00
,,,,,,2,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:27:00
```

I have created a Pandas dataframe and I want to groupby Ltime and Rtime and get the total number of vehicles irrespective of the class (For example total number of vehicles in the Left line (L) in a given time period and total number of vehicles in the Right line (R) in a given time period).

The following is what I tried

```
data = pd.read_csv('output2.txt')
data['Ltime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Ltime'].str.strip())
data['Rtime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Rtime'].str.strip())
data.info()
#   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------              --------------  -----         
 0   LcounterCar         6 non-null      float64       
 1   LcounterTruck       6 non-null      float64       
 2   LcounterBus         6 non-null      float64       
 3   LcounterMotorcycle  6 non-null      float64       
 4   LcounterVan         6 non-null      float64       
 5   Ltime               6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 6   RcounterCar         2 non-null      float64       
 7   RcounterTruck       2 non-null      float64       
 8   RcounterBus         2 non-null      float64       
 9   RcounterMotorcycle  2 non-null      float64       
 10  RcounterVan         2 non-null      float64       
 11  Rtime               2 non-null      datetime64[ns]

data.groupby('Ltime')['LcounterCar'].count().reset_index()

          Ltime     LcounterTruck
0   2021-02-22 13:22:00     1
1   2021-02-22 13:23:00     2
2   2021-02-22 13:24:00     1
3   2021-02-22 13:25:00     2
```

However, the count is always the same. Instead, the following is my expected output.

```
Ltime, count
13:22:00, 1
13:23:00, 3 (two cars and one truck)
13:24:00, 1
13:25:00, 3

Rtime, count
13:25:00, 1
13:27:00, 1
```

Comment: is you sample data right? **LcounterCar** has values 1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an inconsistency between your data and what you describe

- consider left & right as separate data sets
- you describe `sum()` not `count()`,  hence have used `sum()`
- `unstack()` the columns so that it becomes a straight forward `groupby(level=1).count()`
- treat 0 and **NaN** so it's not counted
- pull left and right together using `concat()`
- calc final values

```
1,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:22:00,,,,,
2,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:23:00,,,,,
3,1,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:23:00,,,,,
4,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:24:00,,,,,
5,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:25:00,,,,,
6,2,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:25:00,,,,,
,,,,,,1,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:25:00
,,,,,,2,0,0,0,0,2021-02-22 13:27:00"""))

df.Ltime = pd.to_datetime(df.Ltime)
df.Rtime = pd.to_datetime(df.Rtime)

df2 = pd.concat([
    (df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c[0]==side]]
     .dropna().set_index(f"{side}time")
     .unstack().replace({0:np.nan}).groupby(level=1).count())
    for side in list("LR")]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

#### df

|  | LcounterCar | LcounterTruck | LcounterBus | LcounterMotorcycle | LcounterVan | Ltime | RcounterCar | RcounterTruck | RcounterBus | RcounterMotorcycle | RcounterVan | Rtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:22:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:23:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:23:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:24:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:25:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT |
| 5 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:25:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT |
| 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:25:00 |
| 7 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | NaT | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-02-22 13:27:00 |

#### df2

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-22 13:22:00 | 1 |
| 2021-02-22 13:23:00 | 3 |
| 2021-02-22 13:24:00 | 1 |
| 2021-02-22 13:25:00 | 4 |
| 2021-02-22 13:27:00 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks for this. I have added an image to describe what I want.